# select a record from each group if it has given value in column otherwise any one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

Vendor

```
VendorID  |   City
  1         LosAngels
  2         HongKong
```

VendorDetail

```
VendorDetailID |  DetailCity  | VendorID
      11          Cairo       1      
      12         MosCow       1
      13         Budapest     1
      14         NewDelhi     2
      15         Cairo        2
```

Mastervalues

```
  Text    | Value
LosAngels    LA
HongKong     HK
Cairo        CA
MosCow       Mo
Budapest     BU
NewDelhi     ND
```

The query should return records for every group of VendorID  the City should be @GivenCityValue if any of its record has that value in DetailCity Column otherwise the City Should be the value from City Column of Vendor table

This can be achieved with SubQuery and **Case When** expression.

```
SELECT VendorID,
   (SELECT Text FROM Mastervalues 
    Where Value IN(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM VendorDetail 
                         WHERE VendorID  = Vendor.VendorID AND DetailCity = @GivenCityValue)>0 
                    THEN  @GivenCityValue  
                    ELSE  Vendor.City END)) AS City 
   FROM Vendor
```

if the given value for City is `@GivenCityValue = 'Moscow'` the desired result is

```
VendorID | City
  1         MO
  2         HK
```

But I am trying to do in Join itself. Do we need any user defined aggregate function ?
 Is there any way to do it using join ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT VendorID
     , City
FROM Vendor
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT City = [text]
    FROM Mastervalues
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM VendorDetail
        WHERE VendorID = Vendor.VendorID
            AND DetailCity = @GivenCityValue
            AND value = DetailCity
    ) OR Vendor.City = value
) t
```